# How can I create a pointer to the UINavigation Bar and add a UILongGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I created a view controller and looking for a way to create a pointer to the navigation bar. 
In the storyboard, there is already a UINavigationBar
I got the gesture part down here:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* someGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:theNavBar action:@selector(paintGesture:)];
adminGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1;  // recognize as soon as the touch goes down
//adminGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:adminGesture];
```

but don't know how to call theNavBar

```
UINavigationItem*theNavBarTitle = self.navigationItem;
```

Is that correct? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar
```